# Apache2 Multiview still looking for Anything with keyword in URL

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, routes, multiview

I'm trying to run an AngularJS app on an Apache server with html5mode enabled. I've added a .htaccess per the instructions I've found online, but I noticed when I tried refreshing my localhost/test, apache still loads my test.html instead of the route I have defined in index.html. I tried removing the Multiview option in the httpd.conf file but it still works the same; loading localhost/index still loads up index.html and doesn't throw an error. What else could be causing this and how do I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you expect the HTTP server to respond when you request /test ?

Comment: @covener I expect it to pull up the template URL and controller I have defined in my route in app.js, not just the test.html document.

Comment: HTTPD doesn't know anything about the meaning of your js or dhtml.